# How do I convert this array to a vector?

Tags: c++

```
const int NUM_DIGITS = 7;
int pin1[NUM_DIGITS] = {2, 4, 1, 8, 7, 9, 0};
int pin2[NUM_DIGITS] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 7, 9, 0};
int pin3[NUM_DIGITS] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

Comment: Which one, there are three of them. Also, what have you tried to do, already.

Answer (score 1):

[std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) defines a constructor that takes in two InputIterators and a default allocator with

```
template <class InputIterator>
     vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
             const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

So you can just create a vector from an array like so,

```
std::vector<int> vec(pin1, pin1 + NUM_DIGITS);
```

Comment: Good answer.  Also noteworthy that if the array versions aren't needed for anything you can construct only vectors a la `std::vector<int> pin1 = {2, 4, 1, 8, 7, 9, 0};` etc. (`=` being optional).